# My application object's onCreate was called while my app was running, and my app reset. What would cause this?

Tags: android, multithreading, sqlite

I have a multi-Threaded android application.  One of the things my application does is saves various data to a database on a server via webservices.  I was trying to figure out why things were not saving to the server correctly, and saw in one of my log files, that the application objects onCreate() method and constructor were called in the middle of one of the requests going up to the server.   These request are in the background and are sent via an intentservice.

I have my application set to catch unhandled exceptions and log them, and I did not see anthing in there.  The application onCreate() and constructor was called, the application was kicked back to the main/first screen, the user then had to re-login, and it seems that the database was wiped(which is something else I am wondering about).

So, my main questions are:     Why did the application object onCreate() and Constructor get called(why did the application get killed), why did the database get wiped when the above happened because if I do a force stop from inside of settings, applications, it never kills my db.

Answer (score 1):

two words: low memory

I have the same problem. No solution for now. Try to take advantage of the onLowMemory() method, maybe the OS will spare your app.

My application object gets restarted randomly (not any time) when I am coming back from an external application (ex. camera or gallery) for onActivityResult().

Hope that helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

If the application is not a service, but a 'normal' application that calles your intentservice, it is subject to the normal application lifecycle: this means it will get killed when in the background.

Look for the explaining image on this site: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/activities.html

Take note of the red "Process is killed" part on the left, an the subsequent "onCreate()" afterwards.

[image]

Comment: ok I understand that, but if your Application object gets killed then it starts over/resets the entire app.  Correct?

Comment: If so, what would cause the Application Object to get killed.  This is happening with a few of my users, and I am not sure why.

Comment: As you can see, if the memory is needed, your app might get killed, as simple as that. When the user goes back to your app it doesn't have a running process, so a new one is created. This is a REALLY common thing for android applications. Not so for services btw. If a user does a lot of things while your app does not have focus (or just opens the camera, it uses a lot of mem) your (backgrounded) app WILL get killed.

Comment: ok Well if it restarts, would that cause the db to be wiped.  Also, can I trap a restart or even a force stop from settings, applications?

Answer (score 0):

I've actually seen very similar behaviour that was caused by a NumberFormater trying to parse a null String. After the call to parse(), the application simply reset itself back to the splash screen with no errors at all. Wasn't fun to track down, pretty much stepped through half the code base trying to find out what was happening - the debugger disconnected and the app restarted when stepping past the parse call.

Comment: Ok.  That sounds like what I am experiencing.  Is there anyway to trap that.  I am already trapping unhandled exceptions but that is not what it is.  Also, why would that wipe my db?

Comment: It might be possible that the db was being wrote to when the reset happened, causing it to be blank? No exception was thrown for me, so I put break points everywhere and narrowed it down by which breakpoints were actually getting hit. I would think that it is most likely to happen from your onCreate, onStart or onResume of the activity you're trying to go to, but *shrug* I guess it could be anywhere